# jQuery FullCalendar JSON date issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, date, fullcalendar

I am integrating jQuery plugin [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), overall it has been really straightforward. I however have ran into a problem with adding events to the calendar. I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and have found and followed this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

I am returning JSON to the FullCalendar and the events are getting bound, but they all show up as all day events. I am formatting the dates as ISO8601 format as documented at their site.

**Calendar Javascript**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"
});
```

**JsonResult**

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var fromDate = Utility.Dates.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = Utility.Dates.ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    List<GenericEventList> events = GETGENERICLISTOFEVENTS();
    return Json(events.ToArray()); 
}
```

**JSON Result Value**

```
[{"id":2,"title":"Test Event","start":"2010-03-14T11:00:00","end":"2010-03-14T16:00:00"},
{"id":3,"title":"Test Event1asasas","start":"2010-03-14T10:00:00","end":"2010-03-14T14:00:00"},
{"id":4,"title":"Test Event12","start":"2010-03-14T16:00:00","end":"2010-03-14T17:00:00"},
{"id":6,"title":"Test Event1aaa","start":"2010-03-14T10:00:00","end":"2010-03-14T14:00:00"}]
```

Any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: I found using the blog link above and this blog entry together helped to get my calendar working.  http://john0831.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/asp-net-mvc-jquery-and-fullcalendar/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make sure to set the `allDay` property to `false` for each event object
(http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Comment: Thanks @arshaw, worked like a charm! By the way, fanatic plugin!

Comment: Also, now you can add `allDayDefault: false` to your calendar options to have this be the default.  @arshaw: Thanks so much for the calendar, it's be a pleasure to use/integrate so far.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your dates aren't padded with zeros, then the events won't show. 

Ex. 2010-9-5 bad

Ex. 2010-09-05 good